# How to use the eigen function to find the root of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I create random matrices comprising vectors drawn from multivariate normal distributions:

```
n <- 5000
R <- matrix(c(1, 0,
              0, 1), 
            nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

mu <-  matrix(c(0,0), 
              nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n, mean = mu, sigma = R)
MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = mu, Sigma = R)
```

now, with the help of transformation random vectors were created from them:

[image: random vectors]

I need to use the `eigen` function to  find the root of matrix -

[image: find matrix A, after it need to find the root]

we get a clue -

```r
ed = eigen(Sigma)
A  = ed$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(ed$values))
```

Comment: any help?.. please

Comment: Can you please clarify what problem you're having? If I assign your sample above to `m`; compute `Sigma <- cov(m)`; and run your "clue", the result  seems to be the root you want (`all.equal(A %*% t(A), Sigma)` is TRUE)